# Dynamic casting between array of objects(base case) and a derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, polymorphism

I have an array of objects whose class is a base class, and the elements of the array are derived classes.

```
    Object *object [kNumPlayers] =
   {
        new Human ("Ms. Jones", 50, 1.0f, 2.0f),
        new Alien ("Mx. Charm", 70),
        new Human,
        new Alien,
   };
```

So here, Object is the base class, and Human and Alien are derived classes. Now my problem is that I need to access each of the objects and add extra functionality. As in, I need to access object[0](which is Human) and add whatever needs to be added. So I tried,

```
   Human human0 = (Human)object[0]; // ERROR:'no matching function to call                  Human::Human(Object*&)'
                        OR
   Human *human0;
   human0 = dynamic_cast<Human*>(object[0]); //ERROR: cannot dynamic_cast 'object[0]' (of type 'class Oject*') to type 'class Human*' (source is not polymorphic)'
```

Comment: You base class needs at least one virtual function.

Comment: with raw pointers you should write `Human* human0 = (Human*)object[0];`

Comment: How do I then access object[0] in Human class?
If i have 2 objects say, `Human* human0 = (Human*)object[0];`  and `Human* human1 = (Human*)object[1]`,  then how do I say "if (object[0]) then - "This is want I want to do"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the `dynamic_cast` to compile, the rule is that the source *class* must be polymorphic class — which means it must have at least one `virtual` function, even be it the destructor only. In your case, the source class is the `Object` class which must be polymorphic:

```
class Object
{
   public:
     virtual ~Object() = default; //at least, it should be virtual
     //etc
};
```

Once you fix that the code should at least compile. However, there are many things you should avoiding using in C++:

- Avoid using C-style arrays (dynamic or otherwise)

  - Prefer `std::vector` or `std::array`.
- Avoid managing memory yourself — that is, avoid using naked `new`.

  - Prefer RAII — in your case use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` whatever suits your need.

That is you should something like this:

```
 std::array<std::shared_ptr<Object>, 10> objects {
        std::make_shared<Human>("Ms. Jones", 50, 1.0f, 2.0f),
        std::make_shared<Alien>("Mx. Charm", 70)
        //etc
 };
```

And cast as:

```
 std::shared_ptr<Human> human = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Human>(objects[0]);
```

Hope that helps.